# Is Dojo offline working? Are there any alternatives?

Tags: javascript, dojo, offline

I'm working on a web app which will need to work offline. I'm looking at [Gears](http://gears.google.com/) right now, but I also found [Dojo offline](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/offline). I'm asking this question because the latest news of it are from 2007, and the hosted [demos](http://docs.google.com/View?docid=dhkhksk4_8gdp9gr#demos) don't seem to work (I've installed Gears under Firefox 3.0 on my Ubuntu laptop)
Is anyone using Dojo offline, or an alternative high level offline web application toolkit right now?

Comment: Dojo Offline is built on Gears...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dojo Offline will most likely support native HTML5 offline features in the upcoming browsers (like the latest Firefox release candidate for 3.5), or fall back to using Gears if the user isn't on an HTML5-capable browser. So Dojo Offline provides an abstract layer above the actual implementation which will allow for adaptation to newer offline technologies without having to change your own code.

Answer (score 1):

As the web site you link to states, Dojo Offline is built on top of Gears. The only reason you'd want to use Dojo Offline is if you use the dojo toolkit for other functionality on your site.

Comment: Not sure why I was downgraded.. my answer is correct and relevant to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

It's working even though documentation is still a mess. Have a look at [Dojo offline hello world demo](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.3.1/dojo-release-1.3.1/demos/offline/helloworld/helloworld.html).

Answer (score 1):

Dojo offline has been deprecated for some time (last available at v1.3, currently up to v1.5).